# Express Account program

Tags: java, arrays, object

I need to write a code that entails the following In this project, you will write a program that allows a user to repeatedly create and manage express card accounts.

Each express card is like a debit card, except that it can only be used to purchase meals. A new express card account starts at a balance of $0. The user can

1. deposit money to the express card, increasing the balance (by depositing more money),
2. purchase meals at a fixed rate, thus decreasing the balance, and
3. have meals ( each swipe of the card reduces the remaining number of meals by one).

There are two types of express card accounts:

- a student express account or
- a faculty express account.

All express account have fields   , accountBalance , numberOfMeals , pricePerMeal and baseAmtForBonus.

so far I have and I have no idea where to go from here

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExpAcct{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("MAIN MENU /n 1.) Create a new account /n 2.) Log into an existing account /n3.) Exit the banking system /nPlease enter your selection.");
    int main = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("CHOOSE THE TYPE FOR THE NEW ACCOUNT /n1.) Student express account /n2.)Faculty express account /nPlease enter your selection");
    int accType = scan.nextInt();

}


public class ExpressAccount extends ExpAcct{
public ExpressAccount(int accNumber){

}
public int getAccountNumber(){
    return accNumber;
}
public double getAccountBalance(){
    return accBalance;
}
public double getBaseAmtForBonus(){
    return baseAmt;
}
public double getPricePerMeal(){
    return pricePerMeal;
}
public int getNumOfMeals(){
    return numMeals;
}
public String toString(){

}
```

Comment: Hi, you probably won't get a good answer due to lack of a precise question.

Comment: What do you mean by "where to go from here"? What is the specific question or specific point where you are stuck?

Comment: Try using if statements to get what you want. Try clarifying your post a bit more. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is check what the user enters by doing this:

```
    if(main==1){
        if(accType==1){
            String accTypeWord = "Student";
        if(accType==2){
            String accTypeWord = "Faculty";

}
    if(main==2){
    System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
    //check if password equals their account password
}
    if(main==3){
    System.out.println("Have a good day! Thanks for visiting the bank.");
}
```

When you want to charge them money for buying a meal, you can try this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How much do you have in your ATM account? ");
    double accountBalance = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter cost of meal: ");
    double mealCost = scanner.nextInt();
    int accountBalance -= mealCost
```

This will make it so that the amount you have in your bank will decrease by the cost of the meal. You probably don't want them how much they have in their account, but I have to do that here to show you how to do it.

Here are the steps you need in your program:

1. Use if statements to check which choices they make.(Make new account, log into pre-existing account, etc.)
2. I already showed you how to charge them for buying a meal.
3. Ask for deposit, store this into a double, and add it to the account by doing this:
   accountBalance += depositAmount;

Good Luck and Happy Coding!